# Getting JDBC user permissions for active connection

Tags: jdbc, permissions

I'm trying to come up with proper error codes for connecting to a SQL database via JDBC.  Providing the wrong server name or sql instance is very easy since there's an exception to catch.  Likewise with invalid username/credentials...

But my problem is that if I get a valid connection, I want to get the user's permissions for a specific database.  I could have missed it, but there doesn't seem to be connection.getPermissionsForUser() method or some such thing..  Only thing I can think of is to fire off an insert query to see if I have write permissions or a select query to see if I have read permissions.  Those don't seem very eloquent so I was hoping there might be a better way to do this.

Specifically, is there some way to get the permissions of the user in the connection string?

Comment: Basically you want to check whether you have insert permission if you are inserting a row into a table?

Comment: I suppose that's one way of looking at it--though I'm not really inserting anything at this point.  At this point, I'm just verifying the credentials and I need to know if the credentials have sufficient permissions (to be able to read / write later).